# posisionar contenido segun la eleccion

Tags: jquery

Tengo um problemita al posicionar elementos; es decir, quiero que al hacer click en unos `inputs radio` me muestre **x** contenido según el valor que le corresponda. Para ello agrego el mismo nombre a todos los `input radio` porque solo quiero que se elija una opción. Aquí les dejo el código de lo que trato de hacer

```js
var saleType=function (){//funcion para la seleccion
  var category =$("input[name=selector]:checked").val();

  
 if (category=="truck") {

  alert(category)

   $("#truck").show()

}else if(category=="bike"){
   alert(category)

   $("#bike").show()

}else if(category=="plane"){
   alert(category)

    $("#plane").show()

}else if(category=="boat"){
   alert(category)

     $("#boat").show()
}else if(category=="car"){
   alert(category)

     $("#car").show()
}
}

//ejecutar funcion
  $(document).on("click","input[name=selector]",function(){
         saleType()
          
     })
```

```css
.progress-bar {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background:#fff;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;

}
div{
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  background:lightgrey;
  height:300px;

}
ul{

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!--estos radio al clikear me tienen que mostrar los ul segun el valor-->


     <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="truck">
      <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="car">
      <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="bike">
      <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="plane">
      <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="boat">
     </fieldset>
     
     <br>
 <div>   
     <ul id="truck" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4 " >
           <h1>truck</h1>
      </ul>
    
       <ul id="car" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4 " >
          <h1>car</h1>
       </ul>
       
     <ul id="bike" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4 " >
         <h1>bike</h1>
      </ul>
    
      <ul id="plane" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4 " >
         <h1>plane</h1>
       </ul>
    
    <ul id="boat" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4 " >
        <h1>boat</h1>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

Esto funciona a medias, porque cuando trato de volver a mostrar el contenido según el valor me falla, lo que quiero es que si yo hago click en cualquiera de los inputs radio siempre me muestre su contenido correspondiente.

**OJO:** podría hacerlo de la siguiente manera y funcionaria pero quiero algo mas eficiente y menos tedioso

```
 if (category=="truck") {

   $("#truck").show()
   $("#bike").hide()
   $("#car").hide()
   $("#plane").hide()
   $("#boat").hide()

}etc......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción puede ser la de utilizar atributos [data-*](https://api.jquery.com/data/), de esa manera, podrías asignar un parámetro para solucionar tu problema con un [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) y un `if`

Te dejo un snippet de como lo implementaría

```js
//Agrego un listener si los radios cambian 
$('input[name="selector"]').on('change', ()=>
{
    //Obtengo el valor de el radio elegido
    var categoria = $('input[name=selector]:checked').val();
    
    //Por cada elemento que tenga clase progress-bar
    $('.progress-bar').each(function(e){
        
        //Chequeo si el valor de data-val es igual al radio seleccionado, cuyo caso, lo muestro
        if($(this).data('val')===categoria)
        {
            $(this).show();            
        }
        //caso contrario, oculto.
        else
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }

    });

});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background:#fff;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;

}
div{
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  background:lightgrey;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="truck">
          <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="car">
          <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="bike">
          <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="plane">
          <input type="radio" id="Vehicle" name="selector" value="boat">
</fieldset>
         
         <br>
     <div>
          
         <!--Observar que cada ul tiene un data-val igual al value de los radiobuttons.-->
         <ul id="truck" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4" data-val="truck">
               <h1>truck</h1>
          </ul>
        
           <ul id="car" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4" data-val="car" >
              <h1>car</h1>
           </ul>
           
         <ul id="bike" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4" data-val="bike">
             <h1>bike</h1>
          </ul>
        
          <ul id="plane" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4" data-val="plane">
             <h1>plane</h1>
           </ul>
        
        <ul id="boat" class="progress-bar bg-light mt-1 p-4" data-val="boat" >
            <h1>boat</h1>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

**Edit** una posibilidad, si quieres reducir un poco más el código, es utilizar una función que reciba un booleano y de ahí determine la visibilidad, sería algo así

```js
$('input[name="selector"]').on('change', ()=>
{
    var categoria = $('input[name=selector]:checked').val();
    
    $('.progress-bar').each(function(e){    


        $(this).setVisibility($(this).data('val')==categoria);

    });
});

jQuery.fn.extend({
  setVisibility: function(e) {
    if(e===true)
    {
        this.show();
    }
    else
    {
        this.hide();
    }
    
  }});
```

Comment: Genial!! gracias @Pablo Lozano

Answer (score 1):

Podrías aprovechar que el **value** de tus **inputs** es igual a la **ID** de los **ul** que quieres mostrar u ocultar:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $('.progress-bar').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

De esta manera estoy asociando un evento **change** a todos los **input**. Cuando un **input** cambie, lo que hará será ocultar todos los elementos con clase **progress-bar** (clase que comparten los **ul** que quieres mostrar u ocultar) y luego mostraría tan solo el que correspondiese al **radio** seleccionado, aprovechando el **value** de este y concatenándole un **'#'** para que el selector acceda a la **ID**.